# Site does not work when imported to Electron JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

So I recently have been trying to learn how to use electron JS and right off the bat I have hit an issue. I wanted to take an old site that I created a while back and put in an electron to play with, though it gives me errors on importing items. If I run the same files via browser everything is perfectly fine but in electron it breaks down. I need animations in my site so I use animeJS though it cant be used as for some odd reason electron rejects it, but my browser doesn't. The issue is that electron won't import the library "animeJS" I can't understand why

**Electron:**

[image]

**My browser:**
[image]

```js
import anime from 'animejs'


console.log(anime);
function open() {
    anime({
        targets: "div.right",
        translateX: {
            value: 200,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
    anime({
        targets: "div.left",
        translateX: {
            value: -200,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
}
function close() {
    anime({
        targets: "div.right",
        translateX: {
            value: 0,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
    anime({
        targets: "div.left",
        translateX: {
            value: 0,
            duration: 500
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Underscores</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="back.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script src="button.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     
    


      
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Personally, I don't think you can expect someone to dig through all these tiny screenshots and all those code snippets. I would have stripped it down to the absolute minimum.

Comment: @UweKeim the issue is that it wont import the library "animeJS" i cant understand why

Comment: @joshau You need to read about [mcve] and improve your question in that direction before the community can help you.

Comment: @Frederik.L i removed all extra code, kept the part that has an error

Comment: try saving the anime.js file along with your jquery.min.js file on  your hard drive and get them from there instead of getting them from a url since Electron has a few problems with loading external js. I'm not posting this as a answer since I don't have much to back it up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this via one having the script load in the header and then have the JS file load up with in the .onLoad() function as I was working with canvas, i.e. the anime JS.